# Can't run my vb.net project other computers after publish

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, publish

I made a small game in vb.net using vs2012 and I'm having trouble on the release/publish aspect. It works great and debugs, but now I want to take it and play on other computers. I have read a lot of ways to do it. I also watched a lot of youtube on it, but in the end I didn't succeed at making it work.

I already tried the publish option and making a setup file, but it wont work on my old 32bit winXP Laptop, even when I install the .Net Framework on it. What I really want is to make small .exe and run it with no setup, if its really possible. If it's not possible, then what is the right way to publish or release it with all the images and icons I have on the game?

Comment: Windows XP is no longer supported. This means it doesn't get any patches... even critical security patches. It's irresponsible to continue using it.

Comment: Its a 10 year old laptop I don't use it its just to test stuff on it, if I had any thing better then I would use instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your published Visual Basic project can only support Windows Vista / Vista 64 bit / 7 / 7 64 bit / 8 / 8 64 bit. Windows XP is no longer supported.

Comment: ok but can i make an exe file that will run not only on my pc?

Comment: Yes, as long as the pc has the operating systems I listed.